# Команда .dance для Discord python bot

Tags: python, discord

У меня возникла проблема. Я пишу функцию .dance для python бота, чтобы он отправлял embed  с gif(гиф нужно брать из соседней папки), но возникает ошибка. Помогите если не трудно.

```
@bot.command()
async def dance(ctx):
    embed = discord.Embed(color=0xff9900,title="Танцует.")
    embed.set_image(url="VID-20220319-WA0000.mp4")
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Answer (score 1):

Сначала нужно создать файл, а затем указать ссылку на его вложение. Ну, и сам файл отправить вместе с сообщением:

Здесь `200w.gif` - название файла на ПК, `shrek.gif` - название при загрузке в дискорд.

```py
@bot.command()
async def dance(ctx):
    file = discord.File("200w.gif", filename="shrek.gif")
    embed = discord.Embed(color=0xff9900,title="Танцует.")
    embed.set_image(url="attachment://shrek.gif")
    await ctx.send(file=file, embed=embed)
```

**Результат:**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]